# Unable to get correct match start and end offsets

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex as below:

```
$regex = qr/(?sx-im:(?sx-im:(?:^|(?<=\n)))(?=(?sx-im:[\ \t]*)(?sx-im:(?:^|(?<=\n))Data\ and\ value)(?sx-im:[\ \t\r]*(?:$|\n))))/;
```

I am matching it against following text:

```
$text ="Data and value";
```

Now I want to get the match-start offset, match-end offset and matched text.

Normally I use `@-`, `@+` and `$&` to get these like below:

```
if($text  =~ m/$regex/) 
{
        print "START Offset = ".$-[0];
        print "END Offsset  = ".$+[0];
        print "Matched Text = ".$&;
}
```

In this case, **match is successful** but I am not able to get correct offsets and matched text. Its just printing `0` as both match-start offset and match-end offset. And its printing empty for matched-text.

I want to understand different components of this regex. Specifically what is this `(?sx-im:`, and **how to get matched text**.

Please don't ask me the reason for such regex or suggest me to change the regex. This is a software generated regex. I have simplified my problem for the sake of question.

Please guide me where to start understanding this regex and get match offsets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is in your regex, not your understanding of match offsets. It is matching a zero-width string at the start of the string, and correctly reporting start and end offsets of 0.

Now *why* it matches this is another good question. You can split the regex thus (untested):

```
qr/(?sx-im:
  (?sx-im:(?:^|(?<=\n)))
  (?=(?sx-im:[\ \t]*)(?sx-im:(?:^|(?<=\n))Data\ and\ value)(?sx-im:[\ \t\r]*(?:$|\n)))
)/x
```

And you can see the two sequential halves of it:

- The first matches the start of line or a lookbehind match of `\n` - i.e. both are zero-width.
- the second is a lookahead match of a whole load of stuff, but again is a zero-width match.

You appear to be trying to do too much with a regex, in particular matching the start and end of lines. Consider reading your source file line-by-line and processing individual lines rather than trying to do it all with a regex.

Comment: can u please point out the portion of regex which is matching  zero-width string?

Answer (score 4):

`(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group. It does not create a backreference.

Similarly, `(?= ... )` is a zero-width look-ahead assertion. It does not include the matching string into `$&`.

See [Extended Patterns](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns).

Comment: thanks for perldoc link...the regex and its components are clear to me now